# How to assign already created material with node editor?

Tags: materials, node-editor, transparency

[image]

I created the bottle in the "Blender Render" and I created the glossy look material and applied the color in the "Cycles Render" but I am not able to apply that material on the bottle so that it changes its color. Also, after applying the color I want to make bottle a bit transparent. Please suggest what am I missing.

Advance thanks for those who help me! :-)

Comment: The shading mode is set to "solid" in your image. Set it to 'material' or 'rendered' (material won't show all material's aspect in Cycles). This is the icon just on the right of "object mode". To add transparency, maybe a "glass", just mix a "glass" shader in your node setup (renderable in "rendered" mode)

Comment: Okay cool thanks buddy! but after applying it the surface is not looking glossy as looking in the preview

Comment: Probably because the scene is empty: no light, no other object to reflect...

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to do to make this work.

1. Change to Render Mode.
2. Learn how to add a HDRI image to your enviroment
   so that your material have something to reflect.

[image]